# 2010 Cascading Drop Downs - Question about table that uses the cascade feature

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Dumb question.

First of all I am following this method of using cascading drop downs http://www.uccorner.com/253/sharepoint/cascading-drop-down-sharepoint-foundation-2010/

On the custom list where I will access the other 2 lists and the cascading function. What column type do I make the fields? Are they drop down column or are they single line of text, etc.?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Those fields will be Lookup column in custom list and you have to use the internal names of fields in "relationshipListParentColumn" & "relationshipListChildColumn" section of "Cities"(in this example).